# JDK 8 и знак подчеркивания (_)

Tags: java, символы

Почему с версии JDK 8 , знак подчеркивания (`_`) не рекомендуется употреблять
в качестве идентификатора?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому, что он [зарезервирован для использования в будущем](http://git.net/ml/lambda-development-java/2013-07/msg00350.html).

> We are "reclaiming" the syntactic real estate of "_" from the space of
>   identifiers for use in future language features. However, because
>   there are existing programs that might use it, it is a warning for
>   identifiers that occur in existing syntactic positions for 8, and an
>   error for lambda formals (since there is no existing code with
>   lambdas.)